# Instruction's representation in a virtual machine

Tags: c, interpreter, file-format, vm-implementation

I'm implementing a VM in C (it's my first one) and in order to be platform-independent, I set that each instruction occupies 4 bytes in the binary input (ie the bytecode file).

**My question is**: *what is the current practice regarding instruction's representation?*

Do you simply set unsigned char [4] to represent each instruction? Or, use whatever representation you fancy, provided you can transform those 4 byte instructions onto it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the length of instructions fixed at 32 bits? Or can they have extra operands that extends the length?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: They can have extra operands, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use simple and "classic" stack-based VMs, where the byte-code is just that, bytes. Everything is stored as a large array of `unsigned char`, which is also what I write to/read from files.

I overcome things like byte-order by always writing and reading operands in a specific order. It is a little slower to do four byte-sized reads to get a 32-bit integer, but I don't have to worry about endianess like I would if I used casting to read a single `int`.

Another way to not worry about byte-order, is to simply and *clearly* state in the manual what the byte order is, and that trying to run a binary file on a system with another byte order will result in weird errors. Then you can use an array of e.g. `int32_t` instead to store instructions and operands. It will probably simplify your coding a lot if that's the smallest unit in the byte-code.